# Convert function objects to strings/text?

Tags: r, string, function, text, tostring

Has anyone converted a function in R into a string or text object?

Let's say for a simple square function, I'd want to convert to a text file:

```
sqfxn <- function(x){
  # Get square of x
  # Expect: 
  # > sqfxn(2)
  # > 4
  output <- x^2
  return(output)
}
```

Is there a function that will convert `sqfxn()`to a string object?

```
fxn_to_text <- function(x){
  # convert function x to text
}
```

Which will result to:

```
> txt_fxn <- fxn_to_txt(sqfxn)
> print(txt_fxn)
> "function(x){
  # Get square of x
  # Expect: 
  # > sqfxn(2)
  # > 4
  output <- x^2
  return(output)
  }"
```

Thanks!

Comment: See this is actually not exactly a duplicate because user wants to keep comments within function. But don't know how to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Using `capture.output()`:

```
fun <- paste(capture.output(sqfxn), collapse = "\n")
cat(fun)
# function(x){
#   # Get square of x
#   # Expect: 
#   # > sqfxn(2)
#   # > 4
#   output <- x^2
#   return(output)
# }
```

Comment: Oh okay, will try this one out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm rooting for dput:

```r
sqfxn <- function(x){
  # Get square of x
  # Expect: 
  # > sqfxn(2)
  # > 4
  output <- x^2
  return(output)
}

dput(sqfxn)
```

Comment: Tried dput - the problem is that the resulting object remains a function. Thank you though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `body` which as the name suggests returns the body of the function.

```
body(sqfxn)

#{
#    output <- x^2
#    return(output)
#}
```

However, this does not capture comments written inside the function.